# Rails Model field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model by the name Estimation in Rails which has a field by the name request_type_id. RequestType is a model by itself. The possible values of the request_type field for all objects of Estimation class is fixed (medium, low, high).

The RequestType Model has an auto generated id and Name as the available fields. I am planning to insert the three values, low, medium and high in the model and these will have id's 1,2 and 3. So is the below class design correct?

```
class RfsEstimation < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :request_type
```

Comment: You may use an Enum : http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep fixed value for particular attributes then it is always good to define that particular column as enum

eg:- Add `request_type` as one of the column or attributes for `RfsEstimation` model with integer datatype.

```rb
class RfsEstimation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum request_type: { low: 1, medium: 2, high: 3 }
end
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if you find it useful @user3311539.

Answer (score 0):

Since RfsEstimation holds the foreign_key for RequestType, you'll want to use a `belongs_to` association.

```
class RfsEstimation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :request_type
```